# Pytorch C++ (libtorch) outputs different results if I change shape

Tags: c++, neural-network, pytorch, reshape, libtorch

So I'm learning Neural networks right now and I noticed something really really strange in my network.
I have an input layer created like this

```
convN1 = register_module("convN1", torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(4, 256, 3).padding(1)));
```

and an output layer that is a tanh function.

So it's expecting a torch::Tensor of shape 
{/*batchSize*/, 4, /*sideLength*/, /*sideLength*/} which is and will output a tensor of just 1 float value.

As such for testing I have created a custom Tensor of shape {4, 15, 15}.

The really weird part is what's happening below

```
auto inputTensor = torch::zeros({ 1, 4, 15, 15});
inputTensor[0] = customTensor;
std::cout << network->forward(inputTensor); // Outputs something like 0.94142

inputTensor = torch::zeros({ 32, 4, 15, 15});
inputTensor[0] = customTensor;
std::cout << network->forward(inputTensor); // Outputs something like 0.1234 then 0.8543 31 times
```

So why is the customTensor getting 2 different values from my network just from the fact that the batchsize has changed? Am I not understanding some parts of how tensors work?

P.S. I did check and the above block of code was operating under eval mode.

Edit: Since it's been asked here's a more indepth look at my network

```
convN1 = register_module("convN1", torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(4, 256, 3).padding(1)));
batchNorm1 = register_module("batchNorm1", torch::nn::BatchNorm2d(torch::nn::BatchNormOptions(256)));

m_residualBatch1 = register_module(batch1Name, torch::nn::BatchNorm2d(torch::nn::BatchNormOptions(256)));
m_residualBatch2 = register_module(batch2Name, torch::nn::BatchNorm2d(torch::nn::BatchNormOptions(256)));
m_residualConv1 = register_module(conv1Name, torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(256, 256, 3).padding(1)));
m_residualConv2 = register_module(conv2Name, torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(256, 256, 3).padding(1)));

valueN1 = register_module("valueN1", torch::nn::Conv2d(256, 2, 1));
batchNorm3 = register_module("batchNorm3", torch::nn::BatchNorm2d(torch::nn::BatchNormOptions(2)));
valueN2 = register_module("valueN2", torch::nn::Linear(2 * BOARD_LENGTH, 64));
valueN3 = register_module("valueN3", torch::nn::Linear(64, 1));
```

And how it forwards is like so

```
torch::Tensor Net::forwadValue(torch::Tensor x)
{
    x = convN1->forward(x);
    x = batchNorm1->forward(x);
    x = torch::relu(x);

    torch::Tensor residualCopy = x.clone();
    x = m_residualConv1->forward(x);
    x = m_residualBatch1->forward(x);
    x = torch::relu(x);
    x = m_residualConv2->forward(x);
    x = m_residualBatch2->forward(x);
    x += residualCopy;
    x = torch::relu(x);

    x = valueN1->forward(x);
    x = batchNorm3->forward(x)
    x = torch::relu(x);
    x = valueN2->forward(x.reshape({ x.sizes()[0], 30 }))
    x = torch::relu(x);
    x = valueN3->forward(x)
    return torch::tanh(x);
}
```

Comment: Does the same happen when you apply `toTensor()`, e.g. `std::cout << network->forward(inputTensor).toTensor()`?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the network? With just the convolution you provided, the output would have shape `{batchSize, 256, 15, 15}` and applying tanh afterwards keeps the dimensions, which doesn't result in a single value. Also verify that `customTensor` is unchanged after the first call, you could potentially modify it in-place within the network.

Comment: @ SzymonMaszke my library doesn't seem to have a toTensor() function for torch::Tensor class.


@MichaelJungo The entire network is quite complicated but I added a more indepth look at how it is constructed and how it's called. I also verified that the custom tensor wasn't changed between calls. This is because I actually created the tensor twice, I just simplified it for pasting on stackoverflow.

Comment: That looks all just fine. I've tried running it and it produces the exact same output, as expected, when running it in eval mode, although I needed to change the the reshape for the first linear, since the output at that point is of shape `{batchSize, 2, 15, 15}`, which means it needs to be `x.reshape({ x.sizes()[0], 2 * 15 * 15 })`. If you're only using these modules, the only thing I can see is that a `BatchNorm2d` wasn't set to eval (maybe it wasn't registered as a module), you could check them individually with  e.g.`network->batchNorm1->is_training()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANK YOU @MichaelJungo turns out you were right in that one of my BatchNorm2d wasn't being set to eval mode. I was unclear how registering modules worked in the beginning (still am to an extent) so I overloaded the ::train() function to manually set all my modules to the necessary mode.

In it I forgot to set one of my BatchNorm modules to the correct mode, doing so made it all consistent thanks a bunch!